# How to change Column size of varchar type in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table emp :

```
Field   Type       Null     Key     Default     Extra   
id      int(11)     NO      PRI     NULL    auto_increment
name    varchar(20) YES             NULL    
dept    varchar(20) YES             NULL
```

Now I like to change the varchar size of name from 20 to 50.

I have tried with the following SQL queries but the same error shows :

```
ALTER TABLE emp
CHANGE COLUMN 'name' varchar(100);


ALTER TABLE emp
ALTER  COLUMN name varchar(100);
```

This is the ERROR :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>        to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>        near 'varchar(100)' at line 2

Any idea how to change the column size of varchar type in MYSQL ?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE emp MODIFY COLUMN name VARCHAR(100);
```

Or use CHANGE, but that means you have to give the column name twice (because CHANGE allows you to change the name of the column too).

```
ALTER TABLE emp CHANGE COLUMN name name VARCHAR(100);
```

Don't put the column name in single-quotes. Single-quotes are for string literals or date literals.